# How to hide rotating image in half way

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transforms

The snippet is just rotating the given images. Actually aiming to hide the images when it is behind the front visible images.

Demo: https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/EwpLXx

[image]

```css
@keyframes turn {
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(5deg) rotateY(0.5turn);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(1turn);
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

body .container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 700px;
}

body .container .carousel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 97px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: -48.5px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(0);
  animation: turn 20s infinite linear;
}

body .container .carousel .slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 97px;
  user-select: none;
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(36deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(72deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(108deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(144deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateY(216deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(252deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(288deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(324deg) translateZ(280px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=01" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=02" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=03" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=04" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=05" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=06" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=07" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=08" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=09" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=10" alt="" class="slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With `backface-visibility: hidden;`

> The backface-visibility CSS property determines whether or not the back face of the element is visible when facing the user. The back face of an element is always a transparent background, letting, when visible, a mirror image of the front face be displayed.
>
> <sup>[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)</sup>

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XeBYzM)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

body .container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 700px;
}

body .container .carousel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 97px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: -48.5px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(0);
  animation: turn 20s infinite linear;
}

body .container .carousel .slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 97px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(36deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(72deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(108deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(144deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateY(216deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(252deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(288deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(324deg) translateZ(280px);
}

@keyframes turn {
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(5deg) rotateY(0.5turn);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=01" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=02" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=03" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=04" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=05" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=06" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=07" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=08" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=09" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=10" alt="" class="slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with awesome solution. My actual plan is to build something like this https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/bojLQN to show company logos. It would be great if you can give some advice

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Seems to me an accurate answer. Also, it seems to me that now you are asking a quite different question

Answer (score 0):

You could use `backface-visibility: hidden;` which determines whether or not the back face of the element is visible when facing the user.
If you want instead to apply other effects, like opacity fading or others, you could consider using JavaScript.